# How do you deploy MVC 2.0 to IIS6 running .Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, .net-4.0

i have an MVC app and i'm trying to deploy it to a 2008 server running IIS6 with .Net 4 installed. The project is built with VS2010. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to? That's quite a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be any different from what Phil Haack lays out in [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).